# How to take screen image in cuda?

Tags: cuda, screenshot

i would like to get the screen image, and do work with it, then give the result to the cpu. I couldn't find anyting like that, most places suggest to use opengl, but i never used it before (and i think it would be way slower), is there no way doing it only with cuda?

Comment: Use CUDA's interop capabilities with DX/OGL to copy the backbuffer.

Answer (score 1):

> is there no way doing it only with cuda?

There is no way to take a screen image using only CUDA.

You would need to use a graphics API of some sort (DX, OGL, etc.)

Even CUDA "interop" APIs really only allow data exchange between a graphics context and a CUDA context.  They do not provide specific functions that duplicate graphics functions, such as taking a screen shot.

You will need to use a graphics API.  Fundamentally, the question ("how do I take a screen image?") has nothing to do with CUDA.

Comment: just because "take a screen image has nothing to do with CUDA" the question does, since i didn't know there is no way, thanks for downvoting the question, you are very helpful and kind.